# Irregular Behavior with Perl print

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to print out to two different files. For some reason, print statements work fine for one file, but not for the other. When I run this program, filter2.out consists of a single line that reads "Beginning". filter2.err remains empty.

```
open(OUTPUT, "> Filter2/filter2.out");
open(ERROR, "> Filter2/filter2.err");
print OUTPUT "Beginning\n";
print ERROR "Beginning\n";
```

UPDATE: So I was running this at the beginning of a larger program and realized that it only updates the ERROR file in batches or when the file is closed. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: The code looks fine. Maybe some file permission problem.

Comment: This question does provide enough context to really answer the question with anything except a generic reference to error checking.  If you show enough of your code to reproduce the problem, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider adding

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of your script.  These statements will help catch errors that are otherwise silently ignored by Perl.  In addition, consider adding error checking to your `open` calls: in all likelihood, it's not actually opening.  I'd write it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(OUTPUT, "> Filter2/filter2.out")
    or die "Can't open filter2.out: $!";
open(ERROR, "> Filter2/filter2.err")
    or die "Can't open filter2.err: $!";
print OUTPUT "Beginning\n";
print ERROR "Beginning\n";
```

for example, by just adding adding strict and warnings I got:

```
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at .\printer.pl line 6.
print() on closed filehandle ERROR at .\printer.pl line 7.
```

Hmm...!

By adding error checking, I got:

```
PS C:\dev> perl .\printer.pl
Can't open filter2.out: No such file or directory at .\printer.pl line 4.
```

Aah!  Looking, I didn't have the folder.  After I added the folder, everything ran fine.  You'll probably find something similar.

Finally, you should probably also use the modern, lexical file handles.  This helps catch other errors (like re-used handle names.)  Thus, the final script would look like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $output, ">", "Filter2/filter2.out")
    or die "Can't open filter2.out: $!";
open(my $error, ">", "Filter2/filter2.err")
    or die "Can't open filter2.err: $!";
print $output "Beginning\n";
print $error "Beginning\n";
```

Viola!  Now you can see exactly where the problem fails, as it fails, and make sure that other libraries or code you write later can't accidentally interfere with your file handles.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I added an update to my question if you have any additional insight.

Comment: @user984165: you should probably ask that as a separate question :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your files were properly opened. Also it's better to use local variables as file handles instead of bare words:

```
open( my $err, "> Filter2/filter2.err") or die "Couldn't open error: $!"
print $err "Beginning\n"
```